# How to render tinyMCE content as

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, tinymce

I am learning node.js/express/mongoDB and I am creating a blog. I used tinyMCE as the editor but I cannot figure out how to render my input as html. Instead it is displaying the tags around my content. How can I display it as html?

[input with tinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BR2q.png)

[output with no HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLh1E.png)

here is my code for my show page

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3">

                    <%= blog.body %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my blog creation code

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <!-- use TINYMCE for textarea -->
                    <label for="blogContent">Blog Content</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="blog[body]" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10" type="hidden"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>




<% include modal.ejs %>
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#editor',
        plugins: [
                 "image",
           ],
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works perfectly for me. Note, I'm not using node and know very little about it, so adjust accordingly.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="edit" class="mceEditor"></textarea>
```

**Initialization of Tiny MCE:**

```
tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode : "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector : "mceEditor",
            plugins: 'autoresize'
            });
```

**Retrieve HTML From TinyMCE:**

```
let content   = tinyMCE.get('edit').getContent();
```

Comment: Ok I tried that and It did not eliminate any of the tags

Comment: I updated my answer with how I'm retrieving the html from the TinyMCE container.

Comment: Ok I think that is more of what I am missing. I assume that is stored in a js file? Also what database do you typically use?

Comment: Yes, i have that as a js include.

I typically use MySQL and Postgres, but I've done a bit with Mongo as well.

Comment: Do you do anything with content such as selecting the div content will be displayed and using .innerHTML() or anything like that?

Comment: Once you get the content like I did above, you can access any of the html elements inside of it. For example: x = content.getElementById("test"); -- 'content' being the name of the variable declared in my example.

Comment: If this worked for you, please be sure to mark the answer as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using this `<%=` ejs tag, you escape the HTML code. So HTML is not rendered, that's why you see displayed HTML tags.

If you want to unescape the HTML code, use  the `<%-` tag.

`<%- blog.body %>`

More info here https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you should use the `<%-` instead of `<%=` tag for rendering HTML. Good Luck!